# Makefile not executing to the end

Tags: makefile

I have the following makefile but it just executes the 1st command where it builds me the .o files and not the .so files. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
CC    = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall 
LDFLAGS = -shared

TARGET  = Stepper.so
SOURCES = $(shell echo ./*.c)
HEADERS = $(shell echo ./*.h)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
LIBS = liblua523.a

PREFIX = $(DESTDIR)/usr/local
BINDIR = $(PREFIX)/bin

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SOURCES) -o $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

clean: 
    rm $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: Did you try `make Stepper.so`?

Comment: Swap the two whole rules `$(OBJECT):` and `$(TARGET):`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify a different target on the command line, make always builds the first real target found in the makefile.  In this case, the first real target is the first object file, so that's all that's built.

This is why you typically see makefiles with a first target of `all` or similar, which just depends on the various other targets you want built during a standard invocation of "make" with no arguments.

However, your makefile is really not right, in a number of ways.  The fact that it's running it all means you actually only have one source file.  As soon as you have >1 it will fail.

This:

```
SOURCES = $(shell echo ./*.c)
```

is not very efficient; you should use wildcard here:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard ./*.c)
```

This rule:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SOURCES) -o $(OBJECTS)
```

Tells make, "for every object file, if any source file or any header file has changed, recompile it".  Basically, it means that if you change ANYTHING in the directory, EVERYTHING will rebuild.  If you want that you might as well write a shell script and not bother with make at all.

Further, the compiler will fail when you have >1 source file, as it will try to run:

```
gcc -g -Wall -c foo.c bar.c -o foo.o bar.o
```

which is not right.

You don't need to define this rule at all; make has a built-in rule which knows how to build an object file from a source file.  Just replace it with this:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(HEADERS)
```

(no recipe) so make knows that the objects depend on the headers as well as the source.  Note this is not ideal since all objects rebuild if any header changes but it's fine for a simple program.